# Why sometimes endpoint address is empty

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config, wcf-binding

Suppose I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS, can the address in endpoint be empty?
I saw an example at [WCF Tutorial.](http://wcftutorial.net/Binding-and-Behavior.aspx)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MathService"
    behaviorConfiguration="MathServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" contract="IMathService"
      binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MathServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If endpoint address is empty, it will use BaseAddress specified by the ServiceHost when you instantiate your service.